# Host 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, asp.net, google-app-engine

I am getting a MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005) with message Host 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server, where IP == Google.cloud IP.
I do not know if there is a problem because I change the mysql database password and some how Google Cloud stayed with the old. My C# code for connecting Dialogflow Agent with a mysql database through Google Cloud App Engine and a asp.net core 2.1 work fine with localhost credentials but give that 0x80004005 error when I change the connection string with my GoDaddy mysql database credentials. If I give access to this certain host through GoDaddy's cPanel and retry with my agent returns the same error with different Host IP.

The errors have been collected through Google Cloud Logging >selected resource GEA application (https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your console at cloud.google.com
from navigation menu select 
App Engine > Instances and at look `Instances (autoscaled)`
copy VM IPs and add them at your domain panel as `Remote MySQL hosts`, for GoDaddy cpanel.